# Is my inference reasoning correct here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove this argument is valid:

> Hypotheses:
>
> 1. $(p$ or $q)$ implies $r$
> 2. not $r$
> 3. $q$
>
> Conclusion: not $p$

I used modus tollens on steps 1 and 2 to get not $(p$ or $q).$

Then I distributed the not sign using De Morgans law to get not $p$ or not $q.$

Then I grouped the not $p$ or not $q$ and the 3rd hypothesis to get not $p$ using disjunctive syllogism.

Is this correct? I'm not if the disjunctive syllogism step is correct because of the signs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> not $(p$ or $q).$ Then I distributed the not sign using De Morgans law to get not $p$ or not $q.$

This step is incorrect.

After making this correction, you will find that the [premises are inconsistent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636983/21813).